# CakePHP View Sharing w/ ACL (so no need for duplicate view files)

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, acl

Basically all I want to do is, instead of creating 2 unique views for the admin and user interface, I only want to display the CRUD controls next to the items when the admin IS logged in.

Now the way I am currently doing it is checking the Auth session status and echoing out the controller links IF the Auth session has be activated..

But I wanted to know if there are any other (maybe better) approaches anyone might like to suggest.

Comment: Wow I read my post back and its confusing : ) .. I am currently using 1 view for admin (logged in) and user (not logged in). CRUD controls display on listings when logged in and when not logged in, no CRUD controls. Is it better, for any reason to use multiple view files like when baking admin_routing (all cruds duplicated and prefixed with admin_

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question perfectly.

There are, as you realise, several approaches to this all with their pros and cons.

If you want to show the disabled controls, then you'll need to do something like what you already have.

I think I'd be more inclined to separate the views. This approach will allow you to style the *view profile* and *edit profile* views individually, perhaps better reflecting *public* and *admin* styles. You'll still need to check the Auth, of course.

Comment: Leo, thanks for the note on this. I decided to use the same view, but used an if()Auth and only echo the CRUD controls when is authenticated is true. So when logged in, the controls will show, otherwise no controls : ) .. I have a problem with creating more files than truly needed, but your point make sense on an individuation of views. Thanks : )

Comment: Your approach is fine. So long as something works, I don't get too holy about it ;)